# Loop Through Loading Files Error With Same Name

Tags: matlab

I have a question about how to load in data from multiple directories, but the files I need to load all have the same name. Here's what I have thus far:

```
for i = 1:numel(smoothlist1) % loop through smoothing directories
    path2 = sprintf('%s%s/Trade-off_Curves',path1,smoothlist1(i).name);
    cd(path2);
    disp(['Changed directories into  ', path2]);
    data{i} = load('results.xy');  
    end
```

I loop through each directory in a list I call `smoothlist1`.
 Within each '`smoothlist1` directory, I change directories into `~/smoothlist1/Curves/`. Within this directory, there is a file called `results.xy`. I need to load each of the `results.xy` file from each `~smoothlist1/Curves` directory, but I am unsure how to do that. What I have above just loads in the final `results.xy` file in the last `smoothlist1/Curves/` directory.

So the question is, how do I loop through loading in that `results.xy` file from multiple directories? I have tried doing `data(j) = results.xy`, where I add a counter for `j`, but that did not work. I would like to load these `results.xy` files into separate filenames as well.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're on the right track.  Use `data{j}` (with curly brackets) to make it a cell array, so that it can store any kind of data.  Depending on the contents of the data, there may be more efficient ways to store the array (for example if each result is an identically sized 2d array, then a 3d array would be preferable to a cell).

Comment: Hi Peter, I have performed the above, and now data is a 1x10 cell where each cell contains a 12x2 array.  How would I access each of those cells and plot them?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: You said you used `j` as a counter.  As a counter, it should have a single value at a time.  Or better, just use `i` as appears in your edit to the question.  Speaking of question edits, how is the latest code working?

Comment: The latest code works!  Now I am just attempting to plot each cell array, which shouldn't be too difficult!  Thanks Peter!